# Show Hide with Filtering

Tags: jquery

I have developed a accordion kind of thing in wordpress, please check the below image :

[image]

As you can see on clicking the plus sign, text is overlapping, actually the hide  is us **"top:0px"**

What can i do? I have used Bootstrap Table Expandable & ISOTope Filterting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this, by replacing the the MultiFilter and Bootstrap Table Expandable.